# It's concurrent, but what makes it run in parallel?

Tags: go

So I'm trying to understand how parallel computing works while also learning Go. I understand the difference between concurrency and parallelism, however, what I'm a little stuck on is how Go (or the OS) determines that something should be executed in parallel...

Is there something I have to do when writing my code, or is it all handled by the schedulers?

In the example below, I have two functions that are run in separate Go routines using the go keyword. Because the default GOMAXPROCS is the number of processors available on your machine (and I'm also explicitly setting it) I would expect that these two functions run at the same time and thus the output would be a mix of number in particular order - And furthermore that each time it is run the output would be different. However, this is not the case. Instead, they are running one after the other and to make matters more confusing function two is running before function one.

**Code:**

```
func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(6)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    fmt.Println("Starting")
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for smallNum := 0; smallNum < 20; smallNum++ {
            fmt.Printf("%v ", smallNum)
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for bigNum := 100; bigNum > 80; bigNum-- {
            fmt.Printf("%v ", bigNum)
        }
    }()

    fmt.Println("Waiting to finish")
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("\nFinished, Now terminating")
}
```

**Output:**

```
go run main.go
Starting
Waiting to finish
100 99 98 97 96 95 94 93 92 91 90 89 88 87 86 85 84 83 82 81 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
Finished, Now terminating
```

I am following this article, although just about every example I've come across does something similar.
[Concurrency, Goroutines and GOMAXPROCS](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2014/01/concurrency-goroutines-and-gomaxprocs.html)

Is this working the way is should and I'm not understanding something correctly, or is my code not right?

Comment: How many times did you actually try it?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Running https://play.golang.org/p/1OslDJyfwN6 several times gives me different results.

Comment: There's very good article about go scheduling - https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2018/08/scheduling-in-go-part1.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there something I have to do when writing my code,

No.

> or is it all handled by the schedulers?

Yes.

> In the example below, I have two functions that are run in separate Go routines using the go keyword. Because the default GOMAXPROCS is the number of processors available on your machine (and I'm also explicitly setting it) I would expect that these two functions run at the same time

They might or might not, you have no control here.

> and thus the output would be a mix of number in particular order - And furthermore that each time it is run the output would be different. However, this is not the case. Instead, they are running one after the other and to make matters more confusing function two is running before function one.

Yes. Again you cannot force parallel computation.

Your test is flawed: You just don't do much in each goroutine. In your example goroutine 2 might be scheduled to run, starts running and completes before goroutine 1 started running. "Starting" a goroutine with `go` doesn't force it to start executing right away, all there is done is creating a new goroutine which *can* run. From all goroutines which can run some are scheduled onto your processors. All this scheduling cannot be controlled, it is fully automatic. As you seem to know this is the difference between concurrent and parallel. You have control over concurrency in Go but not (much) on what is done actually in parallel on two or more cores.

More realistic examples with actual, long-running goroutines which do actual work will show interleaved output.

Answer (score 3):

It's all handled by the scheduler.

With only two loops of 20 short instructions, you will be hard pressed to see the effects of concurrency or parallelism.

Here is another toy example : https://play.golang.org/p/xPKITzKACZp

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

const (
    ConstMaxProcs  = 2
    ConstRunners   = 4
    ConstLoopcount = 1_000_000
)

func runner(id int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, cptr *int64) {
    var times int
    for i := 0; i < ConstLoopcount; i++ {
        val := atomic.AddInt64(cptr, 1)
        if val > 1 {
            times++
        }
        atomic.AddInt64(cptr, -1)
    }

    fmt.Printf("[runner %d] cptr was > 1 on %d occasions\n", id, times)
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(ConstMaxProcs)

    var cptr int64

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(ConstRunners)

    start := time.Now()
    for id := 1; id <= ConstRunners; id++ {
        go runner(id, wg, &cptr)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("completed in %s\n", time.Now().Sub(start))
}
```

As with your example : you don't have control on the scheduler, this example just has more "surface" to witness some effects of concurrency.

---

It's hard to witness the actual difference between concurrency and parallelism from within the program, you can view your processor's activity while it runs, or check the global execution time.

The playground does not give sub-second precision on its clock, if you want to see the actual timing, copy/paste the code in a local file and tune the constants to see various effects.

Note that some other effects (probably : branch prediction on the `if val > 1 {...}` check and/or memory invalidation around the shared `cptr` variable) make the execution very volatile on my machine, so don't expect a straight "running with ConstMaxProcs = 4 is 4 times quicker than ConstMaxProcs = 1".